# HTML coding space in table

Tags: html, html-table

I have a a form full of tables and am in need of help to remove the spacing , I want the tables to touch not have spaces between here is a sample table:

also new to html coding so please help

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" svmx-data="{{$D.Inspection}}" width="100%" 
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="theader" style="width: 25%;" svmx-data="{{$D.Inspection.Dry_Pipe_System__c}}">
                                {{$M.Inspection.Dry_Pipe_System__c.label}}</th>
                            <th class="theader" style="width: 15%;" svmx-data="{{$D.Inspection.Trip_Test_Type__c}}">
                                {{$M.Inspection.Trip_Test_Type__c.label}}</th>
                            <th class="theader" style="width: 15%;" svmx-data="{{$D.Inspection.Performed_From__c}}">
                                {{$M.Inspection.Performed_From__c.label}}</th>
                            <th class="theader" style="width:15%;" svmx-data="{{$D.Inspection.Trip_Test_Starting_PSI__c}}">
                                {{$M.Inspection.Trip_Test_Starting_PSI__c.label}}</th>
                            <th class="theader" style="width: 10%;" svmx-data="{{$D.Inspection.Valve_Trip_PSI__c}}">
                                {{$M.Inspection.Valve_Trip_PSI__c.label}}</th>
                            <th class="theader" style="width: 20%;" svmx-data="{{$D.Inspection.Dry_system_low_points_drained__c}}">
                                {{$M.Inspection.Dry_system_low_points_drained__c.label}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the space _around_ each table?

Comment: You have a closing angle bracket (`>`) missing just before `<thead>`.